# Upsert implementation delegates to update but doesn't delegate to add

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, jestjs

I'm not used to javascript or node.js. This is my first try to take it seriously, since my employer asked me to.
Btw, here is my code:

```js
//meta-dao.js
class MetaDAO {
    async getAll() {
        return await Meta.find().exec()
    }
    async getByCatalogId(catalogId) {
        return await Meta.find().where(catalogId).in('catalogs').exec()
    }
    async getById(id) {
        return await Meta.findOne({ id }).exec()
    }
    async add(meta) {
        return await (new Meta(meta)).save()
    }
    async update(meta) {
        return await Meta.update({ id: meta.id }, meta).exec()
    }
    async upsert(meta) {
        var exists = await this.getById(meta.id)
        console.log(exists)
        if(!exists){
            return await this.add(meta)
        }
        else {
            return await this.update(meta)
        }
    }
}
```

```js
//meta-dao.test.js
it('Should insert when upsert a meta with new id', async () => {
    metaDAO.getById = jest.fn((id) => {
        return Promise.resolve(meta)
    })
    metaDAO.getById.bind(metaDAO)

    metaDAO.upsert(meta)

    expect(metaDAO.add).toBeCalledTimes(1)
    expect(metaDAO.add).toBeCalledWith(meta)
    expect(metaDAO.getById).toBeCalledTimes(1)
    expect(metaDAO.getById).toBeCalledWith(meta.id)
    expect(metaDAO.update).not.toBeCalled()
})
it('Should update when upsert a meta with known id', async () => {
    metaDAO.getById = jest.fn((id) => {
        return Promise.resolve(null)
    })
    metaDAO.getById.bind(metaDAO)

    metaDAO.upsert(meta)

    expect(metaDAO.update).toBeCalledTimes(1)
    expect(metaDAO.update).toBeCalledWith(meta)
    expect(metaDAO.getById).toBeCalledTimes(1)
    expect(metaDAO.getById).toBeCalledWith(meta.id)
    expect(metaDAO.add).not.toBeCalled()
})
```

All assertions from the second test case pass. But `expect(metaDAO.add).toBeCalledTimes(1)` from the first test case fails. The console.log prints "null" and I've already tried using:

- `if(exists == null)`
- `if(exists === null)`
- `if(exists == undefined)`
- `if(exists === undefined)`
- `if(exists)`

It doesn't seem to make any difference. The behavior is

- update is called if exists is not null
- nothing is called if exists is null

What am I doing wrong? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mocking was incorrect. Instead of `jest.fn()` and `fn.bind(object)`, I should've used `jest.spyOn` and `spy.mockRestore()`.

The following code is corrected and works!

```js
//meta-dao.test.js
beforeAll(() => {
    metaDAO = new MetaDAO()
})
it('Should insert when upsert a meta with new id', async () => {
    const addSpy = jest.spyOn(metaDAO,"add").mockImplementation(()=>{})
    const updateSpy = jest.spyOn(metaDAO,"update").mockImplementation(()=>{})
    const getIdSpy = jest.spyOn(metaDAO,"getById").mockImplementation((id) => {
        return Promise.resolve(null)
    })
    metaDAO.getById.bind(metaDAO)

    await metaDAO.upsert(meta)

    expect(addSpy).toBeCalledTimes(1)
    expect(addSpy).toBeCalledWith(meta)
    expect(getIdSpy).toBeCalledTimes(1)
    expect(getIdSpy).toBeCalledWith(meta.id)
    expect(updateSpy).not.toBeCalled()

    addSpy.mockRestore()
    updateSpy.mockRestore()
    getIdSpy.mockRestore()
})
it('Should update when upsert a meta with known id', async () => {
    const addSpy = jest.spyOn(metaDAO,"add").mockImplementation(()=>{})
    const updateSpy = jest.spyOn(metaDAO,"update").mockImplementation(()=>{})
    const getIdSpy = jest.spyOn(metaDAO,"getById").mockImplementation((id) => {
        return Promise.resolve(meta)
    })
    metaDAO.getById.bind(metaDAO)

    await metaDAO.upsert(meta)

    expect(updateSpy).toBeCalledTimes(1)
    expect(updateSpy).toBeCalledWith(meta)
    expect(getIdSpy).toBeCalledTimes(1)
    expect(getIdSpy).toBeCalledWith(meta.id)
    expect(addSpy).not.toBeCalled()

    addSpy.mockRestore()
    updateSpy.mockRestore()
    getIdSpy.mockRestore()
})
```

On the other hand the source code was ok already.